# Get the relevant ListViewSubItem by (column) name and not by hardcoding index?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I have a `ListViewItem` *extension method* wrapper that gets the relevant SubItem reference by index (hard-coded), i want to know if there's a way to get it by not hard-coding the index number.

```
public class ListViewExtensionsLogic : IListViewExtensionsLogic
{
    public ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem GetUserIdSubitem(ListViewItem lvi)
    {
        return lvi.SubItems[1]; // I want to get it by not hard-coding it
    }
}

public static class ListViewExtensionMethods
{
        private static IListViewExtensionsLogic _listviewExtensionsLogic;

        static ListViewExtensionMethods()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<ListViewExtensionsLogic>().As<IListViewExtensionsLogic>();

            var container = builder.Build();
            container.BeginLifetimeScope();

            _listviewExtensionsLogic = container.Resolve<IListViewExtensionsLogic>();
        }

        public static ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem GetUserIdSubItem(this ListViewItem lvi)
        {
            return _listviewExtensionsLogic.GetUserIdSubitem(lvi);
        }
}
```

**Being used like this:**

```
        private void InitializeFollowers()
        {
            if (lvFollowList.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvFollowList.Items)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lvi.GetUserIdSubItem().Text))
                    {
                        // Do something here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you pass the index as well as a parameter to the method like below

```
public ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem GetUserIdSubitem(ListViewItem lvi, int index)
{
    return lvi.SubItems[index];
}
```

Comment: Why would i pass the index ? the whole purpose of the this extension method is to act as a wrapper that encapsulates this logic from my code. Besides, the reason i have separated methods that return a SubItem is if in the future i change the order or add/remove a subitem from my listview via design-mode, i could easily change it at the extension methods.

Comment: why would? cause that looks straight forward. isn't it? else you will have to create a indexer for your type where you can pass a column name as well.